# How to force http post wildcard redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I have a large number of pages I would like to force to be http instead of https the code i currently have is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on

RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

How would I add a wildcard redirect to this? maybe

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.com/category/* [R=301,L]
```

It's on a WordPress site if that makes any difference?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

This will redirect `https://hostname/*` to `http://hostname/*`

Comment: So the $1 acts like a wild card indicator? http://hostname/category/* will be redirected, I don't want it to effect every page on the site.

Comment: `$1` means *first matched subpattern* (first block in parentheses)